# Pi Zero W uart not working

Tags: pi-zero-w, uart

I have been trying without any success to setup the uart on my Pi Zero W. When I run tests, the output is blank. I am accessing the Pi Zero W via ssh.

I have added **enable_uart=1** to the /boot/config.txt file.

In rasp-config under serial port interface options, I have answered **No** to the prompt "Would you like a login shell to be accessible over serial?" and **Yes** to the prompt "Would you like the serial port hardware to be enabled?"

Running this command:

```
ls -lh /dev/serial[0,1]
```

Gives me:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 5 Apr 21 19:25 /dev/serial0 -> ttyS0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Apr 21 19:25 /dev/serial1 -> ttyAMA0
```

I have shorted the Uart Tx and Rx.
Here is the test that I am running:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wiringPi.h>
#include <wiringSerial.h>

int main()
{
    int fd;
    if(wiringPiSetup() < 0)return 1;
    if((fd = serialOpen("/dev/ttyS0",115200)) < 0)return 1;
    printf("serial test start ...\n");
    serialPrintf(fd,"Hello World!!!\n");
    while(1)
    {
        serialPutchar(fd,serialGetchar(fd));
    }
    serialClose(fd);
    return 0;
}
```

The output I receive is

```
serial test start ...
```

What am I doing wrong? Any assistance/insight is appreciated.

Running piscope, here is what I get:
[image: UART]

Thank you to everyone. The bug was in the tests and it is now resolved.

Comment: Probably connected the wrong pins

Comment: From the piscope signal, the TX and RX pins seem to be working fine.

Comment: I haven't checked the detailed timings but that looks okay.  Perhaps the receive software is waiting for a end of line.  Try appending /n to the string you transmit.

Comment: I have found a fix for this, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use /dev/serial0 (rather than /dev/ttyS0).

Comment: I have changed it to /dev/serial0 and the output is still the same.

Comment: Try [monitor.py](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#Python_monitor_py) or [piscope](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/piscope.html) to check for activity.  Post a photo showing the connection.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the long wait. I have posted the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Try reconnecting serial device to find exact port.

Refer https://www.instructables.com/Raspberry-Pi-Arduino-Serial-Communication/

Comment: Sorry, I cant find instructions on how to do this in the link you sent

Answer (score 0):

"The output I receive is serial test start ...
What am I doing wrong?"

You should use `/dev/serial0`

There seems to be nothing wrong with the program, it is probably doing what you instructed it to do
i.e. Send a line; then read input and resend the characters **over serial**, presumably producing an infinite loop.

What do you expect it to do?

Incidentally WiringPi is deprecated. You should look into other tools, as it is unlikely to be included in the next Raspberry Pi OS

---

The following code is a program I used to read strings (in the days when I used WiringPi) - this was 7 years ago before `/dev/serial0`, but there are plenty of code samples in other languages or using other libraries.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <wiringPi.h>
#include <wiringSerial.h>

#define MAXLINE 20

/*
 * serialOpenB:
 *  Open and initialise the serial port, 
 *  setting canonical mode, ignore CR on input, no timeout
 *********************************************************************************
 */
int serialOpenB (const char *device, const int baud, const int max)
{
    struct termios options ;
    int fd = serialOpen(device, baud);
    // Get and modify current options:
    tcgetattr (fd, &options) ;
    
    options.c_lflag |= ICANON;  // set canonical mode (line by line)
    options.c_iflag |= IGNCR;   // ignore CR on input
    options.c_cc [VMIN] = max-1;    // return if max-1 bytes received
    options.c_cc [VTIME] = 0;   // no timeout
    
    tcsetattr (fd, TCSANOW | TCSAFLUSH, &options) ;
    
    usleep (10000) ;    // 10mS
    
    return fd ;
}


/* Get a newline-terminated string of finite length.
 *********************************************************************************
 */

char * serialGets (char *buf, const int n, const int fd)
{
    int m;
    m = read (fd, buf, n);
    *(buf+m) = '\0';
    return (buf) ;
}
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <wiringPi.h>
#include <wiringSerial.h>

#define MAXLINE 120
extern int serialOpenB (const char *device, const int baud, const int n);
extern char * serialGets (char *buf, const int n, const int fd);
char * rstrip(char *s) {
    char *p = s + strlen(s)-1;
    while((*p == '\n')||(*p == '\n')) {
        p--;
    }
    *p = '\0';
    return s;
}
int main ()
{
    char tbuf[20];
    time_t ctm;
    struct tm *ltime;
    char line[MAXLINE];

    puts("SerialTest\n");

// Always initialise wiringPi. Use wiringPiSys() if you don't need
//  (or want) to run as root
    wiringPiSetupSys () ;
    int fd = serialOpenB("/dev/ttyAMA0", 9600, MAXLINE);
    for(;;) {
        serialGets(line, MAXLINE, fd);
        ctm = time(NULL);   // log time
        ltime = localtime (&ctm);
        strftime (tbuf, 20, "%F %T", ltime);
        printf("%s %s\n", rstrip(line), tbuf);
        fflush(stdout);
    }
    return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: I have changed the code to /dev/serial0 and the result is the same as before. I expected to receive the sent characters back.

Comment: @agichamba you STILL don't have any code which would display any received characters.

Comment: Thanks for making me realize this. I have written some tests in Python(which I am more at ease with) that have been successful.